# how to make a trigger before insert in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to write a before insert trigger ,

I have table should be like this

| id | cl.2 | cl.3 | cl.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | null | l |
| a1 | 2 | f | m |
| a1 | 3 | t | z |
| a1 | 4 | b | q |
| a1 | 5 | k | e |
| a1 | 6 | d | null |

in case the new.cl.2 = 1 then the cl.3 have to be null other ways should have a value .
and  have i to put the column in NUTT NULL ??

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION check_tijdsteppen()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN    
    IF EXISTS( new.cl.2 = '1' )  
        then new.cl.3 is null, ;
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
    
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER check_tijdsteppen_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON my_table 
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_tijdsteppen();
```

And for cl.4 I don't know what should be the last nummer for each id in cl.2
but i think i can resolve it like by making    a trigger that say if the

```sql
new.cl.2=test.cl.2 + 1 and test.cl.4 is null and new.cl4=test.cl4
```

then i must get out . is it a good idea ? so it is possible to be null only if there is no value in the column is null other ways i cant insert a new value
any hint !

Comment: Assuming your numbers in `cl.2` always start at "1" you can have a simple [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) to make sure exactly those rows have "NULL" in `cl.3` that have "1" in `cl.2`. No need for a trigger to do that. For the second part (making sure the last row has "NULL" in `cl.4`) you most certainly need a trigger.

Comment: `new.cl.3 is null, ;` should be `new.cl.3 = null ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function check_tijdsteppen()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $function$
begin

    if (new.field1 = '1') then  
        new.field2 = null;
        new.field3 = 'none';
        new.field4 = 10;
    end if;
    
    return new;
    
end;
$function$
;
```